# How can I delete my trash/move files to trash?

Tags: trash

1. I have already tried running every command I can find on forums, etc. in terminal and still no luck. The files just stay no matter what.
2. I also can't even move files in other places like downloads, etc. into the trash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which files are you trying to delete? Which commands have you tried?

Comment: Try `gvfs-trash file`

Comment: Or `sudo apt-get install trash-cli` and `trash-put file`

Comment: I've tried rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/* , rm -rf ~/.Trash/* , probably more.

Answer (score 0):

Because I think you are saying is that you want to move files to the trash.

All you really have to do with out using the terminal you just pick the file you want send to the trash right click and go down where it says Move to Trash.

Comment: I do want to move files to the trash, and I've tried right clicking. But I also want to delete them once they're in the trash, and I having trouble doing either.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the file(s) you'd like to send to **Trash**, and press the <kbd>delete</kbd>. This will automatically send them to **Trash**. To empty **Trash**, often you can't right-click the icon on the desktop, but rather open your **file manager**, right click **Trash Can** in the left pane (most likely), and *then* select **Empty Trash Can**.

I had some trouble with that at first. Does this solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click a file or a group of files and press`Shift`+`Delete` to delete them permanently.